# Почему не вызывается конструктор базового класса?

Tags: наследование, python-3.6, конструктор

Не могу понять, почему не вызывается конструктор базового клсса через функцию super(). Интерпритатор выдает вот такую ошбку

> TypeError: descriptor '**init**' requires a 'super' object but
> received a 'type'

```
class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.brand = brand
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.carrying = carrying
        self.car_type = None
        
    def get_photo_file_ext(self):
        return os.path.splitext(self.photo_file_name)[1]


class Car(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, passenger_seats_count):
        super.__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.passenger_seats_count = passenger_seats_count
        self.car_type = "car"


class Truck(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, body_whl):
        super.__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.car_type = "truck"
        self.body_height = self.body_length = self.body_width = 0
        body_characteristic_list = body_whl.split('x')
        if len(body_characteristic_list) == 3:
            if "".join(body_characteristic_list).isdigit == True:
                self.body_length = float(body_characteristic_list[0])
                self.body_width  = float(body_characteristic_list[1])
                self.body_height = float(body_characteristic_list[2])

    def get_body_volume(self):
        return self.body_height * self.body_length * self.body_width




class SpecMachine(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, brand, photo_file_name, carrying, extra):
        super.__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.extra = extra
        self.car_type = spec_machine
```

Comment: super(Car, self).__init__(brand, photo_file_name, carrying) и т.д. оф.док https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Вы пропустили скобки: `super().__init__`.